# Automate SSIS package (File system Deployment) using Devops (Soure control : GIT)

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012

Currently we are using GIT as source control for SSIS packages. We use package deployment model with each package has a relevant .dtsConfig File like the below.

For example,

```
Package1.dtsx
Config1.dtsConfig
```

We have many environments like Dev, Dev-1, STG, STG-1,........ We do SSIS package deployments (File System Deployment) for all the environments manually through DBA assistance.

We planned to automate SSIS package deployments through Devops. In order to do that, we have to create a generic folder structure like the below.

```
Packages
    Package1.dtsx
Dev
    Config1.dtsConfig
Dev-1
    Config1.dtsConfig
STG
    Config1.dtsConfig
STG-1
    Config1.dtsConfig
....
....
```

I mean the package.dtsx file is common for all environments so we place it in Packages folder. Created a separate folder for each environment to place config files.
Since configuration details are changeable based on environment.

I am new to SSIS deployments, I am not sure is this feasible or not.

Is any way we can plan to do the deployments through Devops. What would be the best idea to implement this process. Is any better way we can do it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can setup something you are expecting and keep the same config file. You can update the configuration values while deploying to respective environment using powershell.

Alternatively, you can consider migrating the SSIS solution to Project deployment mode to SSISDB(I Believe it is Available for 2012). Which is most preferred way.